# How do I apply a red border to all <a> elements on a page whose href's appear in an array? (javascript)

Tags: javascript, loops, google-chrome-extension, href

I am making a Google Chrome extension that creates an array of links on a page that meet a certain condition. I want to write a function that then loops through all the  elements (links) on the page and if any of their href's appear on the array of hrefs that my previous function produced, I want to surround that link with a red border. This is what I've written so far but it doesn't work. The way I've tried to do it before the current implementation was assign a class to each of the  elements that appear in the array and then inject a css script into the page that applies the red border to all elements with that class.

```
function highlight(linkArray)
{
  var allLinks = chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,{code:"document.getElementsByTagName('a')"});
  for (var i = 0; i < allLinks.length; i++)
  {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,{code:"document.getElementsByTagName('A')[i].style.border='2px solid red'"});
  }
}
// Below is a rough idea of another way I've tried to got about it but it also doesnt work
// var allLinks = chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,{code:"document.getElementsByTagName('A')"});
// for (var i = 0; i < allLinks.length; i++) {
//   for (var j = 0; j < linkArray.length; j++) {
//       if (allLinks[i] == linkArray[j].href) {
//         chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,{code:"document.querySelectorAll('a[href=`${linkArray[i]}`]')[i].className += 'badLink'"});
//       }
//   }
// }
```

Comment: Not familiar with `executeScript`, but might you put *all* the code inside the `executeScript`'s `code` value?

Comment: Why not add a class to the links "you made" and then style elements with that class?

Comment: You can get all links as `document.links`, so `Array.from(document.links).forEach(link => ...)`.

Comment: executeScript can't see your variable i, you should move entire loop inside executeScript parameter

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you combining your `linkArray` into a CSS selector like this:

`a[href^="link1"], a[href^="link2"], ...`

Then use this selector in `document.querySelectorAll` to get the listed links and `style` them.

So your function would look like this:

```
function highlight() {
  var linkArray = ['bad', 'awful', 'horrible', 'dead'];

  // preparing the code as a string
  var code = `
    document.querySelectorAll(
      '${linkArray.map(l => `a[href^="${l}"]`).join(',')}'
    ).forEach(a => a.style.border = 'solid 2px red')
  `;

  // executing the code
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {code: code});
}
```

The following snippet is a working example:

```js
// Faking 'chrome.tabs.executeScript' to make it work in the snippet.
// You don't need it in your extension.
var chrome = {tabs: {executeScript: (_, {code}) => eval(code)}};

highlight();

function highlight() {
  var linkArray = ['bad', 'awful', 'horrible', 'dead'];

  // preparing the code as a string
  var code = `
    document.querySelectorAll(
      '${linkArray.map(l => `a[href^="${l}"]`).join(',')}'
    ).forEach(a => a.style.border = 'solid 2px red')
  `;
  
  // executing the code
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {code: code});
}
```

```html
<a href="bad">Bad link</a>
<a href="ok">OK link</a>
<a href="awful">Awful link</a>
<a href="horrible">Horrible link</a>
<a href="good">Good link</a>
<a href="nice">Nice link</a>
<a href="dead">Dead link</a>
<a href="bad#2">Bad#2 link</a>
```

Comment: It's best to remove the unneeded confusing code - the architecture of extensions is already quite challenging for newbies.

Comment: @wOxxOm, you're absolutely right, buddy! Thank you, I've updated my answer.

Comment: Snippets aren't used in chrome-extensions tag where inter-process communication is involved such as executeScript so there's no real need to keep it inside the answer with that confusing `chrome` polyfill.